# Расставить знаки препинания в предложении

Tags: лексика

в лесу было темно но мы не спешили домой

Answer (score 1):

В лесу было темно, но мы не спешили домой. А в чем проблема? Это ведь обычное сложное предложение

Comment: И никакой благодарности)